# Extract House Number and Street Name from string using Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to Regex and am trying to use it to parse apart addresses into House Number and Street.

Example: 123 Main St --> ['123', 'Main St']

It gets slightly complicated by the fact that some of my street strings will have hyphenated street addresses, in which case I want to take the first number before the hyphen.

Example: 123-127 Main St --> ['123', 'Main St']

Lastly, I need to be able to handle street names that start with a number.

Most complicated example being: 123-127 3rd Ave --> ['123', '3rd Ave']

So far I've been able to extract the street number, including in the hyphenated scenario, but I'm unsure how to extract the street name which comes after matching the street number pattern.

```
MyString='123-127 Main St'
StreetNum=digit=re.findall('(^\d+)', MyString)
```

Thanks for the help!

Am also editing the question to point out that a dash is not the only character that can separate streets with two numbers. There are three total situations that come up in the data:

1) 123-127 5th St

2) 123 1/2 5th St

3) 123 & 125 5th St

In all 3 of these situations the result should be 123 5th St.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope this is what you're looking for:

```
(\d+).*?\s+(.+)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you. However, I just came across another address type that needs an exception built in.

Something like: '124 & 125 6th Ave' which I would want parsed into 124 and 6th Ave. Do you have a suggestion on how your code above could be altered to handle this type of address? Thanks

Comment: @AJG519 at first you didn't talk about `124 & 125 6th Ave` example. You should provide the full details at the very first.Anyways must first example would work.

Comment: To know for sure I'd really have to know more examples, but this might work: (\d+).*?\s+.*?(\d*[a-zA-Z]+.*)

Answer (score 3):

I assumed that the address part must be at the last and it has exactly two words.

```
>>> s = '123-127 Main St'
>>> re.findall(r'^\d+|\S+ +\S+$', s)
['123', 'Main St']
>>> re.findall(r'^\d+|\S+ +\S+$', "123-127 3rd Ave")
['123', '3rd Ave']
```

`\S+` matches one or more non-space characters.

**OR**

Through `re.split` function,

```
>>> s = '123-127 Main St'
>>> re.split(r'(?<=\d)(?:-\d+)?\s+', s)
['123', 'Main St']
>>> re.split(r'(?<=\d)(?:-\d+)?\s+', "123 Main St")
['123', 'Main St']
>>> re.split(r'(?<=\d)(?:-\d+)?\s+', "123-127 3rd Ave")
['123', '3rd Ave']
```

Comment: Thank you, that's great. And now an unforeseen follow up question.

Ultimately I want to use Pandas to parse apart thousands of addresses using the str extracts method (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.extract.html)

I was under the impression that a pattern with more than 1 group would result in a dataframe, but this doesn't appear to be the case:

Example: pd.Series(['34 West St', '55-56 Green Street', '13-14 4th Ave']).str.extract('(^\d+|\S+ +\S+$)')

Comment: Sorry i don't know about pandas. If you any other questions , ask it as a new one.

Answer (score 1):

```
(\d+)(?:-\d+(?=\s))?\s(.*)
```

Captures the first number, skips a dash and the next number (if present), then captures everything after the space.

```
>>> re.match(r'(\d+)(?:-\d+(?=\s))?\s(.*)', '123-127 3rd Ave').groups()
('123', '3rd Ave')
```