# How to change this regex to match the house number?

Tags: regex

I'm a complete regex beginner, forgive my ignorance.
I want to capture the house number (possibly followed by a letter) from something like `"123 Sesame Street"`

I wrote the following expression: `\d.*+(?=\s)?`

Desired effect:

```
"123 Sesame Street" -> "123"
"123B Sesame Street" -> "123B"
```

Actual effect:

```
"123 Sesame Street" -> "123 Sesame Street"
"123B Sesame Street" -> "123B Sesame Street"
```

My intention with the final question mark is making the whole thing "non-greedy" (I was kind of winging it there). But when I remove it, nothing matches anymore! Now I'm completely lost...

Comment: you can try the following regex: `\d+\w*` meaning

Comment: See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990258/extract-house-number-and-street-name-from-string-using-python-regex, just remove the second capturing group to only capture the House Number.

Answer (score 1):

This one does the job, it maches 1 or more digits followed by an optional non space character:

```
\d+\S?
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sJpxid/1)

Comment: This will match any number in the given string, I am not sure if this is the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This ist Autoit Code.

```
#include<Array.au3>
Global $str = "Hallo 123 Sesame Street"
Global $str1 = "123B Sesame Street"

$re = StringRegExp($str, '(\d+\w*)\s+.*', 3)
ConsoleWrite($re[0] & @CRLF)

$re = StringRegExp($str1, '(\d+\w*)\s+.*', 3)
ConsoleWrite($re[0] & @CRLF)
```